# Is it possible for others to find images on my server that aren't referenced on my website?

Tags: apache, webserver, web-crawler

If I upload a file to my webserver, is it possible for anyone or any crawler of some sort to find that file even though I haven't linked to it from anywhere or referenced to it?

Say for example you have a site that hides content to non logged in users, if I know the path to an image file I am able to reach that file even though I am not logged in. This is the case of several sites I regularly visit. But is this really a problem, is it possible for people with bad intentions to find these images even though they can't log in?

My next question would of course be (maybe that's another thread though): how can I as a web developer, using a LAMP stack, protect file paths from being requested from non logged in users?

Comment: The answer to your question is basically yes. Anything that is not explicity locked down can be found by anybody (human or crawler). Even though the chances are small if there are no links to the specific image(s), you can never guarantee nobody will find it.

Comment: Thanks @Oldskool, but how is that done without simply guessing the file path? What crawlers can do stuff like that and how does it work?

Comment: Crawlers may not necessarily find your images or anything that does not have a link to it. That's not to say they won't. People design malicious crawlers all the time. And those some malicious crawlers will also ignore your `robots.txt` file. There is no 100% sure fire way to keep people from finding what is on your website. Whether you have links to it or not. A lot can be done to keep the "honest" folks out with `robots.txt` and `.htaccess`.